# Applicative Functor instance for functions with the same result type in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement the functor and applicative instances for functions with the same initial type in Scala. My current implementation of the two type classes is:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def fmap[A,B](f: A => B): F[A] => F[B]
}

trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Functor[F] {
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]
  def apply[A,B](f: F[A => B]): F[A] => F[B]
}
```

The problem that I have is that `Function1` has two type parameters and I think I cannot fix only one of them. Is it possible to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is with a type alias:

```
def FunctionFunctor[X] = {
  type F[Y] = Function[X,Y]

  new Functor[F] {
     def fmap[A,B](f: A => B)  = (fa: F[A]) => f.compose(fa)
  }
}
```

Notice the `def`, so you're creating a new functor instance for each specific `X` type.

Other way to do is with type lambdas, which have a funny syntax:

```
 def FunctionFunctor[X] = new Functor[({type F[Y] = Function[X,Y]})#F] {
  def fmap[A,B](f: A => B)  = (fa: Function[X,A]) => f.compose(fa)
 }
```

Try and read about type lambdas, can be an obscure concept if you're not familiar with it. Good read about it is [Scala in Depth](http://www.manning.com/suereth/)